# Why does only one icon appear in my flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm learning to code in Dart/Flutter and I cannot move an icon and don't even place another one

[image]

Comment: Hello there check, Your question lacks Clarity https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also can you post the code as a snippet as opposed to a screenshot of the code, as detailed in the link above, so we can help you better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your are use `floatingActionButton` so you can use this.

Add `floatingActionButtonLocation` property in the `Scaffold`.

```
return new Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation:    
      FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
  bottomNavigationBar: new BottomAppBar(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: new Row(...),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to render two FloatingActionButton in a Column you have to set the herotag property to null.

```
FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.remove
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
        heroTag: null,
      ),
      FloatingActionButton(           
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
        heroTag: null,
      ),
```

In order to separate them you can use a SizedBox between the two FAB or even set the Column property MainAxisAlignment to spaceEvenly or even spaceBetween.

Let me know if this works.